# Extending GridView with default buttons and update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, datagrid

I am trying to extend the ASP GridView control by adding some buttons above it. Such as Insert/Delete/Print etc. I must extend the GridView control because it is used at a lot of places in the project. The buttons and the control must be wrapped in an UpdatePanel so it can do partial updating. I am trying to do something like this:

```
UpdatePanel up = new UpdatePanel();

ImageButton newButton = new ImageButton();
newButton.ImageUrl = "../Images/new.gif";

up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(newButton);
up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(this);

Page.Form.Controls.Add(up);
```

The problem is I don't know where to put it, and I don't even know if this will work. If I put it at OnLoad/OnPreRender I get this:

"The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases."

This error occures on the second add.

If I put it in CreateChildControls Page is not yet created.

Please give me some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I'd probably build my own custom server control that inherits from GridView.

Here's a link to a MSDN article that should get you started:  [Walkthrough: Developing and Using a Custom Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Since you're already creating the custom server control; I think this might be your problem line:  `Page.Form.Controls.Add(up)`

Try using simply `Controls.Add(up)`.  What it looks like you're trying to do is add the update panel to the Page itself; when you should really be adding it to the controls collection of your extended GridView

Comment: Can you update your post with the contents of your RenderContents() method?

Comment: Jim B: I hadn't thought of using the RenderContents() method, that gave me the idea to put something like this there:


        `ImageButton newButton = new ImageButton();
        ...

        newButton.RenderControl(writer);

        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }`

I just need to figure out how to call a method from there.